# PyQt5: Accessing widgets after they've been added with button under the same variable name

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget, qobject

I'm a bit new to programming, but basically, I have a program where a new textbox (and checkbox) shows up every time the "Add task" button is clicked. That means every textbox and checkbox created falls under the same variable (ie. self.textbox or self.checkbox). I need to be able to access each individual textbox and checkbox later on in order to move them around or delete them. What would be the best way to do this? I'm not sure how to programmatically set up different variable names for each textbox/checkbox, and I thought I could access each textbox/checkbox by assigning them unique object names, but that hasn't worked so far.

Here's the pertinent code. Everything works, just I can't move forward without being able to access each widget.

```
def add_task_button_clicked(self):

    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
    self.label = QLabel(self)
    self.label.setText(str(self.counter))
    self.label.move(5, self.i)
    self.btn1.move(50, self.j)
    self.textbox.move(50, self.i)
    self.textbox.resize(280, 40)
    #dynamic object names
    self.textbox.setObjectName("text" + str(self.counter))
    self.textbox.show()
    self.label.show()
    
    #setting up the checkbox for each textbox
    self.checkbox = QCheckBox(self)
    #self.checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.click_box)
    self.checkbox.move(20, self.i)
    self.checkbox.show()
    
    #setting new objectNames for each checkbox
    #checkbox is named with string number 1 through n
    #lists made for all textboxes and checkboxes
    self.checkbox.setObjectName("Checkbox" + str(self.counter))
    list_of_items.append(self.textbox.objectName())
    list_of_checkboxes.append(self.checkbox.objectName())

    self.i += 40
    self.j += 40
    self.counter += 1

    def click_box(self, state):
    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        print("Checked")
    else:
        print("Not Checked")
```

Comment: According to your code, you're always adding widgets using a fixed geometry (position and size), which is also always the same. There is a variable "range" of answers that can be given, but, before that, it's better to understand how you're actually adding those widgets, why you're adding more of them, and how/when/where should they appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add each text box and label to a list:

```
tasklist = []  # list of tuples - (textbox, label)
def add_task_button_clicked(self):

    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
    self.label = QLabel(self)
    .........

    tasklist += (self.textbox, self.label)   # add to object list

    self.i += 40
    self.j += 40
    self.counter += 1

    def click_box(self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print("Checked")
        else:
            print("Not Checked")
```

You can later access the widgets using the list:

```
textbox, label = tasklist[0]  # deconstruct tuple to variables
```

Comment: `tasklist[0]` will always return the first pair of widgets, no matter what checkbox has triggered a state change.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (but not always safest, if you're using threads) method is to use [`sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender), which is a method available to all QObject subclasses (which means also all QWidget subclasses, since QWidget inherits from QObject) that returns the object that has emitted the signal.

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add task')
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_task_button_clicked)

        self.lineEdits = []
        self.checkBoxes = []

    def add_task_button_clicked(self):
        index = len(self.lineEdits)
        count = str(index + 1)
        taskLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(taskLayout)
        taskLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(count))

        lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        taskLayout.addWidget(lineEdit)
        lineEdit.setObjectName('text_' + count)
        self.lineEdits.append(lineEdit)

        checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        taskLayout.addWidget(checkBox)
        checkBox.setObjectName('checkBox_' + count)
        self.checkBoxes.append(checkBox)

        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)

    def textChanged(self, text):
        lineEdit = self.sender()
        print('Line edit "{lineEdit}" (index {index}) has changed text: "{text}"'.format(
            lineEdit = lineEdit.objectName(), 
            index = self.lineEdits.index(lineEdit) + 1, 
            text = text))

    def stateChanged(self, state):
        checkBox = self.sender()
        print('Checkbox "{checkBox}" (index {index}) has changed text: "{value}"'.format(
            checkBox = checkBox.objectName(), 
            index = self.checkBoxes.index(checkBox) + 1, 
            value = ('Unchecked', 'Partially checked', 'Checked')[state]))
```

Another possible solution is to use a lambda for the connection and add the index parameter:

```
def add_task_button_clicked(self):
        index = len(self.lineEdits)
        count = str(index + 1)
        taskLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().addLayout(taskLayout)
        taskLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(count))

        lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        taskLayout.addWidget(lineEdit)
        lineEdit.setObjectName('text_' + count)
        self.lineEdits.append(lineEdit)

        checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        taskLayout.addWidget(checkBox)
        checkBox.setObjectName('checkBox_' + count)
        self.checkBoxes.append(checkBox)

        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(
            lambda text, index=index: self.textChanged(index, text))
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state, index=index: self.stateChanged(index, state))

    def textChanged(self, index, text):
        lineEdit = self.sender()
        print('Line edit "{lineEdit}" (index {index}) has changed text: "{text}"'.format(
            lineEdit = lineEdit.objectName(), 
            index = index + 1, 
            text = text))

    def stateChanged(self, index, state):
        checkBox = self.sender()
        print('Checkbox "{checkBox}" (index {index}) has changed state: "{value}"'.format(
            checkBox = checkBox.objectName(), 
            index = index + 1, 
            value = ('Unchecked', 'Partially checked', 'Checked')[state]))
```

Note that there are two arguments for the lambda, and the second one is a keyword. This is because in both cases the signal emits a single argument (the text for the QLineEdit, the state for the QCheckBox), but we need also the index argument for the function call.
In this case, you could also have avoided the `index` keyword argument, since in the *scope* of the function, `index` is fixed; so, this will also work:

```
        # ...
        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda text: self.textChanged(index, text))
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda state: self.stateChanged(index, state))
```

Using the lambda keywords, instead, is mandatory if you're creating connections using loop cycles, otherwise you'll always end up with the *last* value assigned to index.

Consider this example:

```
    for index in range(10):
        checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        # ...
        checkbox.stateChanged.connect(lambda state: self.stateChanged(index, state))
```

In this case, no matter what checkbox you click, you'll always end up with `index = 9` (the last value assigned in the for loop).

Some further suggestions:

- avoid fixed geometries: they are unreliable, your GUI won't adapt itself when required by the screen size or the user tries to resize the window; use layout managers instead;
- instance attributes (`self.whatever`) are used to keep a persistent reference to the object: if you continuously overwrite them (as you did with `self.textbox`, `self.label`, etc), there's no benefit and is completely unnecessary; the most common and advised way is to use an object container (like a list, as you already did), but you could also use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr); for example:
  `setattr(self, 'text_' + count, lineEdit)`
- calling `show()` is unnecessary if you're creating a widget with a parent that is already visible or you're adding it to a widget's layout;